# HTML5 srcset and sizes

Tags: html, srcset

```
<img src="media/640x320_image.jpg" srcset="media/640x320_image.jpg 320w, media/640x1280_image.jpg 768w" sizes="(min-width:768px) 768px, 320px">
```

What is wrong with the srcset and sizes above? The 640x1280_image.jpg always shows, when I make my window small it doesn't change.

Comment: Which browser are you testing with?

Comment: Google chrome latest

Comment: Seems to work in Firefox for me, but not in Chrome. Not sure why, Chrome supports this. `<img src="http://placehold.it/640x320" srcset="http://placehold.it/640x320 320w, http://placehold.it/640x1280 768w" sizes="(min-width:768px) 768px, 320px">`

Comment: You have pointed me to the right direction, thank you. Chrome is not retrieving a new image when it already has downloaded a bigger before. So I should wrap it in a wrapper to make sure the height is not exceeded: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28155861/google-chrome-version-40-srcset-attribute-problems

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand `media/640x1280_image.jpg 768w`. Do you really use a 640px wide image, but tell the browser it is 768px wide?

It breaks everything in the `srcset` algorithm, for sure.

It looks like you want to use Art Direction to have images of different proportions based on the viewport width.

If this is what you want, you need to use `<picture>`, because `srcset` alone doesn't provide this.